# I cannot add a image by using GUI in python

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

Hello I have a question for python. Even if I write codes like that if I click F5 there is no image. What happend?

```
class Spring(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Frame.configure(self)
    Label(self, text="spring", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack()
    Button(self, text="go back to selection page?",
              command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage3)).pack()
    beauty=PhotoImage(file='beauty.png')
    Label(self, image=beauty).pack()
```

Comment: What makes you think F5 would show an image?

Comment: normally this kind of problem happens because beauty is a local variable and it is not accessible by `root.update()` try to use `self.beauty` or `global beauty` instead